# Unity Camera Quaternion.RotateTowards without rolling/banking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, quaternions

I have a camera facing the ground and I want to pan up to look at a target object in the distance.

Currently, I achieve this with the following:

```
Vector3 dir = targetPoint - transform.position;
Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, lookRotation, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

The camera performs the rotation and ends up pointing at the target object correctly, but as the camera pans up it tilts to one side making my game world set at an angle to the viewer, which is pretty disorienting:

[image: Camera rotation example 1]

How can I constrain the camera angle some way so that the horizon is always flat to the camera?

Thanks!

**Update**

Adding the line suggested by @Isaac below produces the correct rotation in relation to the horizon, but it snaps abruptly to z=0 at the start which is still not what I'm looking for.

```
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
```

[image: Camera rotation example 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent [Q/A on gamedev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/im-rotating-an-object-on-two-axes-so-why-does-it-keep-twisting-around-the-thir) on this subject. You should try the pitch/yaw system suggested there. 
Another suggestion is to correct for the roll of your camera during the rotation.

```
public float rollCorrectionSpeed; 
public void Update()
{
    float roll = Vector3.Dot(transform.right, Vector3.up);
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, -roll * rollCorrectionSpeed);

    Vector3 dir = targetPoint.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, lookRotation, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.rotation = newRotation;
}
```

Edit:
There is an easier solution: Just keep the `z` rotation of the Quaternion you are rotating from to 0.

```
public void Update()
{
    Vector3 angles = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
    Quaternion from = Quaternion.Euler(angles.x, angles.y, 0);

    Vector3 dir = targetPoint.position - transform.position;        
    Quaternion to = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(from, to, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: I also experimented with your second technique and you still get an initial jump instead of a smooth rotation towards the z axis.  I also edited `targetPoint.position` to be just `targetPoint`, since that's what I think you meant.

Comment: Your first solution there solved it! In fact I just set rollCorrectionSpeed to 1 and it worked perfectly. Thanks so much, and also for linking to the gamedev discussion which I found very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Upon experimentation, I found 2 possible solutions depending on what you want.

If you are just trying to follow the target I would recommend using `LookAt`, which automatically aligns to the world up. In your code that would be (in Update) `transform.LookAt(dir);`.

If you need/want the pan effect set the localEulerAngles after updating the rotation. This is what I did which worked:

```
//this is your code
    Vector3 dir = targetPoint - transform.position;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
    Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, lookRotation, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.rotation = newRotation;

//this is what I added
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
```

The addition simply takes the way the camera is facing after updating the rotation using the quaternion and sets the z rotation to zero.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

new information/edits:

I believe I have found a solution, but it is ugly and I would appreciate feedback as to whether it stutters, etc.

This code is essentially the same as before, but now it checks to see the z angle and edits it more manually using a variable I called `zDamping` which affects the speed at which the camera rotates around the z access only.

I added outside of update:

```
public float zDamping; //public only for testing, it's convenient for finding an optimal value
private bool rotationCheck = false;
```

And then inside `update()`:

```
//This is your code (unchanged)
        Vector3 targetPoint = target.transform.position;
        Vector3 dir = targetPoint - transform.position;
        Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (dir);
        Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards (transform.rotation, lookRotation, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);

//This is what is new (remove my addition from before edits or it won't work)
        if (transform.localEulerAngles.z >= 180f && transform.localEulerAngles.z <= 359f && !rotationCheck) {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z + (rotationDamping * zDamping));
            transform.rotation = newRotation;
        } 
        else if (transform.localEulerAngles.z <= -180f && transform.localEulerAngles.z >= 1f && !rotationCheck) {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, transform.localEulerAngles.z - (rotationDamping * zDamping));
            transform.rotation = newRotation;
        }
        else {
            transform.rotation = newRotation;
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (transform.localEulerAngles.x, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0);
            rotationCheck = true;
        }
```

As I said, this solution is pretty ugly but it might work. You'll have to see what `zDamping` values work for your speeds to look natural (I recommend starting with .01). There will also be a small "jump" once you get close to the value, but the closer you make `359f` to 360 and `1f` to 0 the smaller that jump will be. The danger with making it too small is if you overshoot, but it should work even if it overshoots, but it will take a small amount of time.

Test it out and let me know what you think, sorry I couldn't find something more elegant right now. I also experimented with adding a separate Quaternion to exclusively rotate the z axis, but it did not work; feel free to experiment with that and if you want I can give more details about what I did.

Good luck and again, sorry for the sloppy solution.

Comment: Hi @Isaac, thanks for your help so far. I need a smooth rotation hence using Quaternion.RotateTowards, I tried adding in your line and whilst it does keep aligned to the horizon now, at the start it jolts towards z=0. Any idea on how to solve this?

http://i.imgur.com/WXqiIln.gif

Comment: Thanks for all your help @Isaac, Pluto's answer ended up being the simplest and right one for me. If I could give you some of the bounty I would!

Answer (score 0):

Added a code in your line, hopefully it'll solve the problem.

```
Vector3 dir = targetPoint - transform.position;
Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dir);
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, lookRotation, rotationDamping * Time.deltaTime);
newRotation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(newRotation.eulerAngles.x,newRotation.eulerAngles.y,transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

Comment: This doesn't actually rotate towards zero, it simply maintains the current z rotation.  For example, if you start with a z rotation of -10, it will stay at -10 instead of rotating to zero.

Comment: Yepp, that's what I thought @bbeckford needed